# Print array key without value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good afternoon, I am doing a little exercise and I have a problem, I will expose you:

```js
var elements = [
     { 
        name: 'Banana',
        price: 200,
        qty: 31,
        imported: true,
        size: [12, 40, 60],
        type: null
    },
    {
        name: 'Pomelo',
        price: 55,
        qty: 325,
        imported: false,
        size: [5, 50, 55, 79],
        type: '-'
    }
];
```

Get a result like this on the console

[image]

```
for(let i=0; i<elements.length;i++)
{
    console.log("***" + elements[i].name + "***");
    console.log("size:"+ elements[i].size);
}
```

I have this code and it works, but in the second console.log, how can I get the key out of the array without having to type "size" manually?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean get the key out of the array?

Comment: Use a `for .. in` loop instead of a regular for loop? `Object.keys` could also help. Also since you already know the keys, you can print them as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size key like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<elements.length;i++)
{
    console.log("***" + elements[i].name + "***");
    console.log(Object.keys(elements)[4] + ":" + elements[i].size);
}
```

But this will work when the **size** key is always on the 4th index as it is in your elements object

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys` to access keys of an object.

```js
var elements = [
  { name: 'Banana', price: 200, qty: 31, imported: true, size: [12, 40, 60], type: null },
  { name: 'Pomelo', price: 55, qty: 325, imported: false, size: [5, 50, 55, 79], type: '-' }
];

elements.forEach((element) => {
  Object.keys(element).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(`Key: ${key}`);
    console.log(`Value: ${element[key]}`);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful for you

```js
var elements = [
 { 
    name: 'Banana',
    price: 200,
    qty: 31,
    imported: true,
    size: [12, 40, 60],
    type: null
},
{
    name: 'Pomelo',
    price: 55,
    qty: 325,
    imported: false,
    size: [5, 50, 55, 79],
    type: '-'
}]

elements.forEach(x => {
  console.log("***" + x.name + "***");
  console.log("size :", x.size.join(","));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object format is constant and `size` property always remains at the same position (second last),

```
const objKeys = Object.Keys(elements[i]); // ["name", "price" , ...]
const yourKey = objKeys[objKeys.length-2]; // returns "size"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite basic with JS, you start by learning JS through any source of your choice, you can take Udemy course or join a free code camp (https://www.freecodecamp.org/)

```
for(let i=0; i<elements.length;i++)
{
    console.log("***" + elements[i].name + "***");
    console.log("size:"+ elements[i].size.join());
//  console.log("size:"+ elements[i].size.toString());
}
```